# Are Custom Taxonomy Templates Possible?

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, archives

I am trying to have some information specific to a taxonomy term appear above that taxonomy's archive list.

Example: Taxonomy is 'Sports', with football, soccer, and baseball being terms within the 'Sports' taxonomy. I would like to have a small description of each sport display above that term's archive page.

In researching this possibility, I have read the [Category Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates) page, [found a plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-content-header/) that appears to do what I want, but only with regard to Categories and not custom taxonomies.

I would do it with Categories, but I have multiple taxonomies now and cannot use the simple categories solution any longer :(

Am I being dense, or are custom taxonomy templates not possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Custom Taxonomy templates are entirely possible, the order of the template loading is,

1. `taxonomy-{sometax}-{someterm}.php` - If the taxonomy were sometax, and
   taxonomy's slug were someterm
2. `taxonomy-{sometax}.php` - If the taxonomy were sometax.
3. `taxonomy.php`
4. `archive.php`
5. `index.php`

This template hierarchy give you tons of control on how you want to alter the display of taxonomies as a whole, as a group or alone.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

For example in your case you can create a template called `taxonomy-sports.php` and then customize it however you want using conditionals, template tags and functions.

Comment: That worked perfectly, Thank you!

(edit: for the record, it was necessary to use the taxonomy-sports-soccer.php style of naming)